# Worpress Тема Cactus убрать заголовки и навигацию страниц

Tags: css, wordpress, шаблоны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отключить отображение `.page-title-bar` в Worpress теме **Cactus** на всех страницах?

Comment: display: none не судьба?

Answer (score 0):

Если display:none; в корневом файле не сработает, откройте визуальный редактор вверху кнопка Настроить. Выберите пункт Пользовательские стили или что-то подобное и вставьте туда это условие. При таком костыле сработает 100%.